# Dimension of Ker(T) when $T(A) = \operatorname{Tr} {(A)}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For a positive integer $n > 1$, let $ T: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(A) = \operatorname{Tr} {(A)}$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries. Determine the dimension of $\ker{(T)}$.

I can see just by looking at this transformation that it's not one-to-one. But I'm sort of stuck. I know the zero matrix and matrices with diagonal entries of 0 are examples of tr(A) = 0. But I still can't really see what the dimension is. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the dimension theorem. What is the dimension of the range of $T$?

Comment: Hmm. If that's the case, the only thing I can think of rank(T) = n - 1. Thus making null(T) = 1. But that looks and seems wrong. :/

Comment: How could the dimension of the range of $T$ be dimension $n-1$ when it lives in $\mathbb{R}$, which is a 1-dimensional space?

Comment: Also, remember that the dimension of the domain is $n^2$, not $n$.

Comment: Wow, /facepalm. I see it now, thank you for helping me see something so simple. :P

Answer (score 3):

Eric's way is probably the easiest and most canonical. Here is another one, along the same lines, but more explicit: one can prove that $$
\ker T=\{x-\frac{T(x)}n\,I_n:\ x\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}\}.
$$
Indeed, it is easy to see that the set on the right is in the kernel of $T$. And, conversely, if $T(x)=0$, then $x$ is of the required form.

Also, any $x$ can be written as $\frac{T(x)}n\,I_n+(x-\frac{T(x)}n\,I_n)$, which shows that $\mathbb R^{n\times n}=\mbox{Im}\,T\,I_n+\ker T$. And this is a direct sum, because if $y=T(x)\,I_n$ and $T(y)=0$, then $y=0$.

Thus we have that the dimensions of $\ker T$ and $\mbox{Im}\,T$ add to $n^2$. So 
$$
\dim\ker T=n^2-1.
$$

Comment: It is clear that you work with $\rm{II}_1$ factors ;-) I would bet that the OP had the non-normalized trace in mind, which sends $I_n$ to $n$. So you would need to adjust your parametrization of $\ker T$. Also, $\mbox{Im} T$ is not in $M_n$, so it should be $(\mbox{Im} T)I_n +\ker T$ in your subspace equation.

Comment: Quite rigorous, but it makes sense. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good points. Thanks, Julien!